# Can't open a sheet on a window twice

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I'm opening a sheet on a window , the first time the sheet opens
correctly, but if I close it, and try to open again it doesn't work, I
just get the system alert sound.

```
- (IBAction) showSpeedSheet:(id)sender
{

 [NSApp beginSheet:addEditPackagePanel
    modalForWindow:[[NSApp delegate] window]
  modalDelegate:nil
    didEndSelector:nil
    contextInfo:nil];

}

-(IBAction)endSpeedSheet:(id)sender
{

 [NSApp endSheet:addEditPackagePanel];
 [addEditPackagePanel orderOut:sender];


}
```

I can't find what's wrong, the app doesn't print any error on the log.

Comment: Where does `addEditPackagePanel` come from? I can make something along the lines of your code work — provided, I have a valid window to use as the sheet. That said, you should totally go with MattM's suggestion and provide the sheet's logic in a delegate.

Answer (score 4):

A delegate is not required.

The beep occurs because the system believes there is already a sheet open on the window (whether or not that sheet is technically visible).  It's not the greatest error reporting, but that's what it is.

In my code sheets have window controllers and I do both of the following steps in every action that is attached to a sheet-closing button:

```
[NSApp endSheet:[windowController window]];
[windowController close];
```

With these steps, subsequent sheets are able to display without beeping.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to implement the modal delegate and didEndSelector.  The orderOut should be called from the did-end selector.

```
[NSApp beginSheet:addEditPackagePanel
 modalForWindow:[[NSApp delegate] window]
 modalDelegate: self
 didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:)
 contextInfo: nil];
```

and

```
- (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo
{
    [sheet orderOut:self];
}
```

I believe control is sent to the did-end selector has soon as endSheet is called.

Comment: The modal delegate and its did-end selector are not _strictly_ needed — they are a way to provide for a cleaner architecture. In fact, you _can_ make the code shown above run without errors.

Comment: danyowdee, thanks for the fast reply. I've tried that methodology from MattM. No way. I put the breakpoint on the didEndSheet. Pointed the delegate in IB and , as I see delegate is obviously pointed in "modalDelegate:+self" parameter but+it's never called:(